# Web.config - T4 Transformation - SMTP section

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web-config-transform

Hey Guys I'm trying to do a transformation of the SMTP section of a web config file.

This is what I have got so far:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="25" userName="UserName1Here" password="Password1Here" defaultCredentials="false" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Then inside the .production version of the Webconfig I have this:

```
<mailSettings>
<smtp xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="25" userName="UserName2Here" password="Password2Here" defaultCredentials="false" />
</smtp>
```

Can't seem to get it working... what am I missing any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it...

What I was missing was the route element of the web-config file.
Which was

```
<system.net>
```

So now this works

```
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="25" userName="UserName2Here" password="password2here" defaultCredentials="false" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Hope this helps someone else.